# Adding a CSS Border on Hover and Removing It in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to add a class to a group of floated list items on hover using jQuery.

I add the class and then remove the added space from the newly-inserted border using `margin:-4px` so that the list items do not shift around.

That's my intention at least. it's not working. Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NgXSc/1/

Note how the sibling list items shift on hover. The intended result is the very last list item where upon hovering, nothing moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your margin problem is being caused because although you initially define the margin to be `margin-right: 19px`, you overwrite it with `margin: -4px !important`.

Also, there's no need to use jQuery for this - just use the `:hover` CSS pseudoclass.

I modified your code to produce your desired results:

HTML:

```
<nav id="cs-client-list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav><!--end cs-client-list-->
```

CSS:

```
#cs-client-list { padding: 25px; }
#cs-client-list li {
    background: yellow;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 19px 0 0;}
#cs-client-list li a {
    text-indent: -99999px;
    width: 111px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 4px solid transparent; /* use page's background color (ie #fff) if you want the border to display outside the box */
    display: block; }
#cs-client-list li a:hover { border-color: #000; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/NgXSc/26/

Comment: Thanks again. Yea, it's for everyone's friend IE6

Comment: Well, keep your jQuery with the hover() function and just use your `.over` class in place of my `:hover` pseudoclass. Your welcome!

Answer (score 1):

`margin: -4px` is not a relative change to 19px. It completely replaces it.

Figuring out that padding adds 4px to both the left and right, you want to subract 8 pixels from the margin and use `margin-right: 11px` for the `.over` class. This keeps the list items in their original positions.

See the change in code here: http://jsfiddle.net/NgXSc/21/

Answer (score 0):

Set a transparent border (or set the `border-color` to the `background-color` of the element) on the non-hovered element equal to the width of the visible border on the hovered-over element. And remove the `!important`; it's not necessary, just use specificity:

```
#cs-client-list li a{float:left;display:block;text-indent:-99999px;height:80px;background-color:yellow;width:111px; border: 4px solid transparent;}

#cs-client-list li a.over{border:4px solid #000;cursor:pointer;}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NgXSc/16/)

This does not need jQuery, not even in IE6...

Answer (score 0):

Dont mess about with negative margins. Change your `.over` class to

```
#cs-client-list li a.over{ border: 4px solid #000; width: 103px; }
```

This is the quickest way to get your desired effect without applying a transparent border to the non-hover state `li a` elements.